# unable to get the item in list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get the item which has GCC in it from the below  using ansible

```
pool= [
        "P-SCC.COM_443",
        "P-GCC.COM_443"
    ]
}
```

here is my code to do it and its giving an error as "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f3f8ebdf280>",

```
- name: set route 
  set_fact: 
    route: "GCC"

- name: filter pool name
  set_fact:
    filtered_pool: "{{ pool | select('search',  route ) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f3f8ebdf280>"***

A: Ad the the filter *list* to the pipe

```yaml
  filtered_pool: "{{ pool|select('search',  route )|list }}"
```

This filter is not needed in recent versions. If you can update to a [supported version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/release_and_maintenance.html#releases-and-maintenance).